# Convert an ImageIcon to a Base64 String and back to an ImageIcon without saving to disk?

Tags: java, base64

I'm trying to store an imageIcon bas a Base64 String.

This is what I have so far:

```
public ImageIcon getImageIcon() {
    if(imageIcon == null || imageIcon.isEmpty()){
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            byte[] btDataFile = Base64.decodeBase64(imageIcon);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(btDataFile));
            return new ImageIcon(image);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon imageIconIn) {
    imageIcon = Base64.encodeBase64String(imageToByteArray(imageIconIn));
}

public static byte[] imageToByteArray(ImageIcon imageIn) {
    try {

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageIn.getIconWidth(), imageIn.getIconHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // FIX
        Graphics g;
        g = image.createGraphics();
        imageIn.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
        // END FIX

        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", b );

        g.dispose();

        return b.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I get a black rectangle instead of the image.

I'm using Java 1.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

******************************** . FIXED . ******************************

I found a working solution and updated the above code.

********************************  EDIT  *********************************

Added g.dispose() after painting icon.

Comment: First, by not including relevant information like the declaration of `imageIcon`. String?

Comment: Please provide Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example so that we can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Glad you found a working solution.  I hope that if my answer (below) which told you what you did wrong (writing out the bytes of an black image) and how to fix it (draw `imageIn` into you new `image`) was what lead you to your solution, you'll click the "This answer is useful" button. In any event, editing your question post to include the "fix" is not the correct action. If you feel you've answered your own question, then post your solution as an answer, and mark that answer as correct. You'll even earn the "self learner" badge. That marks the question as answered, instead of leaving it open.

Comment: Note: you fix is incomplete.  `Graphics` objects you create **must be disposed**.  You must add the call `g.dispose()` after you've finished drawing into `image`.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a brand new `BufferedImage`, with width & height same as the given image.

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
        imageIn.getIconWidth(), 
        imageIn.getIconHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

Note that the image is empty.  No content has been written to it.   The bytes will all be zero, and RGB 0x000000 is black.

Then, you are writing the bytes of this black image to your `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", b );
    return b.toByteArray();
```

Of course, when you convert that byte buffer back to an image, it will be black.

You will want to draw/copy `imageIn` into your new `image` before you write out the bytes.

But if you don't mind using whatever the current image's format is, you could just write out that image instead of converting it to `TYPE_INT_RGB`...

```
Image image = imageIn.getImage();

// write image to ByteArrayOutputStream
```